# Getting error: RPC failed; HTTP 411 curl 22 while cloning git repository using https

Tags: java, git

I am using https url to clone a git repository.

I am getting this error while cloning a repository.

```
error: RPC failed; HTTP 411 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 411
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
while cloning the git repository.
```

I increased git postbuffer size to 500 MB

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

but it did not resolve the error.

Can anyone please let me know what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Which repository are you trying to clone? How exactly are you calling Git for cloning the repository?

Comment: I am trying to clone a repository I created on my server using 

git clone https://<server>/<repo_address> @sk_pleasant

Comment: Are you using a proxy (or anything that proxies data, like a non-default antivirus or firewall, TLS middlebox, or similar)?

Answer (score 1):

An HTTP 411 code means that the server or a system in the middle, such as a proxy, non-default antivirus or firewall, or TLS middlebox (all of which are proxies), refuses to accept the request without a valid `Content-Length` header.

In general, such a configuration will not work with Git.  Git uses HTTP/1.1 chunked transfer encoding (or similar techniques in HTTP/2) to stream pack data to the server.  This avoids allocating lots of memory needlessly and makes things much more efficient.  The message you're getting means that either the server hosting the repository or some sort of proxy is misconfigured and needs to be fixed so it will work properly with Git.

Note that chunked transfer encoding has been a mandatory part of the HTTP specification since HTTP/1.1 was released in June 1999, so every server or proxy speaking HTTP on the modern Internet is going to have to implement it to conform to the standard.